# Update On-premises AD user profile using Azure Function

Tags: c#, .net, azure, active-directory, ldap

We have an on-premises AD where user profile needs to be updated when our HR application data gets updated.

Since there is a limitation is MS that we cannot writeback from azureAD to on-premises AD (ADConnect is used to update on-premises to AzureAD, not the other way), directly updating on-premises AD is our only option.

To do that I basically tried the https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/513767/Set-Update-Active-Directory-attributes-to-user with System.DirectoryServices (LDAP) and it works well in a local console application. I need to do exactly what's on this link, using cloud.

I am looking for an idea that do this in Azure cloud such as an Azure Function. When I checked the Azure hybrid connection on azure function apps do not allow on-premises AD update access.

Please suggest a approach that works for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you’ve got a domain controller vm in azure then you could install the hybrid worker extension and use an automation account.